# WCF service call causes TypeLoadException

Tags: wcf

I have a WPF program calling a WCF service. it all works fine on my PC but on a customer PC I get the following error.

> [Footer][Header]2011-12-20 10:54:29,809 [5] WARN 
>   Kern.Common.Logging.Logger - Error logging in - An exception occurred
>   during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException
>   for exception details. 2011-12-20 10:54:29,928 [5] WARN 
>   Kern.Common.Logging.Logger - Inner Exception -
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ChannelBase`1' from
>   assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    at
>   KernMobile.Data.Server.KernMobileWcfService.KernServiceClient.CreateChannel()
>   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()    at
>   KernMobile.Data.Server.KernMobileWcfService.KernServiceClient.KernMobile.Data.Server.KernMobileWcfService.IKernService.BeginLogin(String
>   username, String password, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState) 
>   at
>   KernMobile.Data.Server.KernMobileWcfService.KernServiceClient.OnBeginLogin(Object[]
>   inValues, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InvokeAsync(BeginOperationDelegate
>   beginOperationDelegate, Object[] inValues, EndOperationDelegate
>   endOperationDelegate, SendOrPostCallback operationCompletedCallback,
>   Object userState)

I turned on WCF tracing but there are no errors reported in the log file.

Here is the service config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IKernService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/Kern.Server.Service/KernService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IKernService"
          contract="KernMobileWcfService.IKernService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IKernService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that .NET framework v4.0 is installed on the client machine and also check if all the dependant dlls are available?

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this.

It was caused by using a portable library project as a wrapper for the WCF service reference.

This worked fine on most PCs but failed on a customers locked down hardware. I'm assuming some supporting DLL's were missing.

I changed changed over to a normal class library project and all worked.